# Prove that each diagonal of a quadrilateral lies either entirely in its interior or entirely in its exterior.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, proof-writing

From Kiselev's Planimetry problem 55.

Here's my attempt at a proof, I'd appreciate feedback on how to get better beyond whether or not it's correct, as I have very little experience and am still uncomfortable with the format.

Consider any quadrilateral with vertices labeled ABCD in clockwise order starting from any vertex.

By definition, the only diagonals are AC and BD.

For a diagonal not to be either completely inside or outside of the quadrilateral, it would have to cross one of the quadrilateral's sides.

Considering for example the diagonal AC, it would have to cross AB, BC, AD or DC.

But lines can intersect at most at one point

Therefore AC couldn't cross AB since both lines already intersect at point A.

For the same reason, AC couldn't cross any of the other three sides BC, AD or DC.

By the same reasoning, We can show that this is true for diagonal BD as well.

Therefore, since neither diagonal can cross any side of the quadrilateral, each diagonal has to be either entirely inside or entirely outside of the quadrilateral.

Comment: This works only for a *convex* quadrilateral. But the it is trivial from the definition of a convex set. What's your definition of a quadrilateral?

Comment: @Bernard, I guess my definition would be a polygon with 4 sides, not necessarily convex. Why doesn't my proof work for all quadrilaterals? It seems to me that it works even for non-convex ones.

Comment: sorry, I was reading on a small screen, and saw only the beginning of the question (‘… lies entirely in its interior’). I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @Bernard No worries, thanks. Can you tell whether the proof is correct, though?

Comment: It is correct for me. I just would turn the phrasing ‘lines can intersect at most at one point’ into  ‘`distinct` lines can intersect at most at one point’.

Comment: @Bernard, Got it, I understand the distinction you're pointing out. Thanks for coming back and checking, I appreciate it; it feels good to get it right even though it's obviously very simple.

Comment: What's not so obvious, actually, is the assertion that a straight line which has a point on both sides of another line must intersect that line. It's a not-so-easy problem of topology of the plane, that relies on properties of the system of real numbers.

Comment: @Bernard Wow, that's way beyond what I know...is there a simple way to avoid that and use simpler properties instead?

Comment: At a lower level, some (intuitively evident) properties must be taken as axioms.

Comment: I see, thanks. Hopefully one day I'll get to Topology and will understand what you're saying above!